# Graphical Layout showing in Eclipse But Not showing when emulator runs

Tags: android, layout, android-emulator

I have developed a simple Hello World Example With Nexus Emulator. Emulator runs But when I click on lock button on Emulator, The Graphical Layout does not show.

MY MainActivity.Java file source code here

```
package com.myNewProject.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Activity_main.xml file code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have run emulator many times.

Answer (score 0):

Did you launch it in the android manifest file. You have to launch there. Thanks
Here is an example..

```
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
```